# How to apply SSMS 2008 R2 color scheme to SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have been using SSMS 2008 R2 (Sql Server Management Studio) for quite some time and hence have got used to its colour scheme.

[image]

Now I have installed SSMS 2012 and its colour scheme is all different.

[image]

Is there a way to import these colour settings from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012?

Comment: You can manually change the colours in the settings, but honestly I would just spend some time getting used to the new shceme - it's much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you spend some time getting used to the new shceme - it's much improved. However, if you feel you cannot get along with it you can change the colours in *Tools* -> *Settings* -> *Environment* -> *Fonts and Colours*. Show settings for *Text Editor* and edit the colours/styles there. For your table/column colour the item you need to select in the *Display items* list is *Identifier*:

[image]